# String regex in Java for Twitch-Bot

Tags: java, regex, bots, twitch

Currently I'm programming a Twitch-Bot with pIRC on Java.

I want to sort out commands like e.g `!<command> [<tagged-user>]`

For now I use that code:

```
private boolean checkForCommand(String message) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(!)\\w+");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(message);
    return m.find();
}

public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login,String hostname, String message){
    String user = sender;
    if(checkForCommand(message)){
        String[] arguments;
        if(message.split("\\s+").length > 1){
            arguments = message.split("\\s+");
        }else {
            arguments = new String[1];
            arguments[0] = message;
        }
        String command = arguments[0].substring(1, arguments[0].length());
        if(arguments.length > 1){
            user = arguments[1];
        }
        respondForCommand(command,user); // User gets respond for his command.
    }
}
```

I get for example `!info testuser`:

`testuser [here is the command response]`

I want to improve the code by only regex-ing the hole process.

Basically I want a regex what reads out the command-name and if there is someone tagged it should also read the tagged username.

Kinda like `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("!COMMANDNAME [TAGGEDUSER]");`

Thank you for helping me, I struggelt alot with regex lately, but I want to understand it. Online regexing wont help me much.

Comment: Do you mean something like that: `![A-Za-z]+(\s\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\]){0,1}`? This pattern matches `!Qwertz` and `!Qwertz [Something123]`

Comment: @Blobonat Why use `{0,1}` instead of `?`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Because I find it more readable, but there is no special reason.

Comment: @Blobonat something like that, but I would love to get as a result the COMMANDNAME and the TAGGEDUSER. Is it possible to get it in an array? something like

`array = {COMMANDNAME,TAGGEDUSER};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use capturing groups. Your current regex puts the '!' in a capturing group for some reason, but it doesn't use it. Instead, put the parentheses around the important parts of the pattern that you want to capture.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^!(\\w+)(?:\\s+(\\S+))?");
```

What we have here is:

- A "!"
- One or more word characters that are expected to be the command. They are surrounded by parentheses, so they are the first capturing group.
- Then a non-capturing group for an optional argument. Since it's optional, we add a '?' after this group. In this group:

  - One or more spaces
  - A capturing group for one or more non-spaces

So basically, we have two capturing groups, but one of them will not be matched if there is no argument.

Now if you call `matcher.find()`, you can use `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)` to access the captured groups. `group(2)` may return null as it won't be matched if there is no argument.

Demonstration code:

```
public class SimpleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^!(\\w+)(?:\\s+(\\S+))?");
        Matcher matcher;
        String[] testStrings = { "!command john", "!command john something", "!commandWithoutArguments",
                "!commandNoArgsButSpaces   ", "Not A command." };

        for (String testString : testStrings) {
            System.out.print("String <<" + testString + ">> ");
            matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String command = matcher.group(1);
                String user = matcher.group(2);
                if (user == null) {
                    user = "default";
                }
                System.out.println("is a command: " + command + " user: " + user + ".");
            } else {
                System.out.println("is not a command.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
String <<!command john>> is a command: command user: john.
String <<!command john something>> is a command: command user: john.
String <<!commandWithoutArguments>> is a command: commandWithoutArguments user: default.
String <<!commandNoArgsButSpaces   >> is a command: commandNoArgsButSpaces user: default.
String <<Not A command.>> is not a command.
```